# How do you prove the uniform convergence of the following series?

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Consider the series
$$
\phi(t)=\sum^{k\geq0}\frac{w^k}{1+kt}
$$
where $w\in\mathbb{C}$ and $0<|w|<1$. This series is allegedly easily shown to be uniformly convergent in a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}-\{-1,-1/2,-1/3,\ldots\}$, but I don't see how. Can anybody fill in the gaps?

Comment: As shown in the answers, this series does not converge uniformly on all sets satisfying the conditions given. However, if the compact set does not contain $0$, i.e. a subset of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{\color{#C00000}{0},-1,-1/2,-1/3,\dots\}$, then the convergence will be uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the compact subset of the complement
$$
K=\left\{-\frac1{k+k^{-k}}:k\in\mathbb{Z},k\ge2\right\}\cup\{0\}\tag{1}
$$
No matter how large $n$ is, for $t=-\frac1{n+n^{-n}}$, we have
$$
1+nt=\frac1{n^{n+1}+1}\tag{2}
$$
whereas for $k\ge n+1$, we have
$$
1+kt\le-\frac{1-n^{-n}}{n+n^{-n}}\le-\frac{3/4}{n+1}\tag{3}
$$ 
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k\ge n}\frac{w^k}{1+kt}\ge w^n\left[\left(n^{n+1}+1\right)-\frac{4(n+1)}3\frac{w}{1-w}\right]\tag{4}
$$
Since $(4)$ does not vanish, the sum does not converge uniformly on $K$.

Comment: But i didn't ask to prove that it does not converge uniformly on $K$, I want to show that my series converges uniformly in a compact subset of the set I state in the question

Comment: The set I give fits all the criteria for the set you give. You do not give a particular set, you just said "a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}-\{-1,-1/2,-1/3,\ldots\}$". It does not converge on the set I give, so it is not possible to show that the convergence is uniform on a general set that satisfies the given conditions. If you have a particular set in mind, please state that.

Answer (score 0):

Let $K = \{0\} \cup \{(-1 + i/(2w)^k)/k \mid k \ge 1\}$.

$K$ is compact and doesn'contain any $1/k$.

However, if $t_k = (-1 + i/(2w)^k)/k$ then $w^k/(1+kt_k) = -i2^k$,

and so
$|\phi(t_k)| \ge 2^k - \sum_{k' \neq k} |w^{k'}/(1+k't_k )|
 = 2^k - \sum_{k' \neq k} |kw^{k'}|/|k-k'+k'i/(2w)^k| $

Since $|k-k'+ki/(2w)^k| \ge |k-k'| \ge 1$,
$|\phi(t_k)| \ge 2^k - \sum_{k' \neq k} |kw^{k'}| \ge 2^k -k \sum_{k' \ge 0} |w|^{k'} = 2^k-k/(|w|-1)$.

As $k \to \infty$, $|\phi(t_k)| \to \infty$, so $\phi$ is not bounded on $K$.

If the convergence was uniform then $\phi$ would be continuous and bounded on $K$, so the convergence is not uniform.